# Melhor aplicabilidade para tornar uma interface funcional

Tags: java, interface, java-8

A partir do java 8, para que uma interface torne-se funcional, esta precisa ter apenas um método certo ? Porem temos a anotação @FuncionalInterface, que define explicitamente que esta interface é funcional.

Mas qual a principal diferença em usar ou não esta anotação, se com apenas um método ela já se torna funcional ?

```
    @FunctionalInterface
public interface FuncionalInterface <T>{
    boolean valida(T t);
}

public interface FuncionalInterface <T>{
    boolean valida(T t);
}
```

Ao imprimir o resultado é o mesmo tanto com a anotação ou sem, vejam no main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FuncionalInterface<String> funcionalInterface = valor -> valor.matches("[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}");
    System.out.println(funcionalInterface.valida("45680-000"));

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme descrito na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), essa anotação serve primariamente para declarar a sua intenção de que ela seja usada como uma interface funcional.

Um dos aspectos envolve deixar essa intenção explícita e documentada no código, o que é uma boa prática.

Documentação que faz parte do código permite uma série de facilidades que não necessariamente afetam a execução do sistema, mas podem servir como dica para a sua IDE completar corretamente o código, para o compilador executar alguma operação ou verificação adicional ou mesmo para o próximo programador que for usar suas classes e não vai ler o manual do sistema.

Neste caso, como também citado na documentação, está anotação exige que o compilador emita erros nos seguintes casos:

- O tipo em questão não é uma interface
- A interface não atende os critérios de uma interface funcional

Então a principal diferença é que se você adicionar mais um método nas duas interfaces que você colocou na pergunta, uma vai compilar e a outra não.

Pense no caso de uma interface que é usada por outro sistema e não apenas pelo seu próprio código. Adicionar mais um método pode não fazer mal algum no seu código, mas pode quebrar o código de terceiros.

Portanto, de forma prática, o mínimo que a anotação faz é lembrar você cada vez que você para a classe que não é uma boa ideia colocar mais um método ali.

Comment: Fiz o teste adicionei mais um método, e a IDE acusou erro, no caso entende agora a anotação evitar que se outra pessoa pega seu código, e ter uma interface funcional, não adicione mais métodos nela, exemplo caso uma interface seja funcional sem a anotação, outro programador pode tenta torna-la genérica, exemplo você tem uma interface  para um DAO caso não tenha anotação nela sinalizando olha eu sou uma interface funcional, outro cara pode pensar eu tenho uma interface com so um método vou tomar essa merda um DAOgenerico, entendeu? No caso interface funcional so pode ter métodos default?

Comment: @HashMap Não sei se entendi sua dúvida do último comentário. Infelizmente você não pode evitar que alguém use uma interface qualquer como o funcional. Porém, quando você cria classes e interfaces, chame isso de API, você estabelece um contrato com quem vai usá-las e cabe a quem vai usar obedecer o contrato. Se uma classe não tem a anotação e depois o código da pessoa quebra porque foi adicionado mais um método, a culpa é dela por não obedecer o contrato, logo ela precisa mudar o código. Sobre o método default não entendi. Você está falando sobre implementação de métodos em interfaces?

Comment: Agora entendi eu que confudir as coisas valeu , orbigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Você não precisa fazer nada de especial para que uma interface seja considerada
funcional. O compilador já identifica esse tipo de interface pela sua estrutura.

A anotação `@FunctionalInterface` servepara que o fato de
ela ser uma interface funcional não seja pela simples coincidência de ter um único
método. Para fazer isso, usamos a anotação `@FuncionalInterface`:

Marque sua interface com a anotação e acione mais um método qualquer nela, logo vera que o compilador acusara um erro.

Comment: Fiz este teste e realmente o popio IDE aponta um erro.

Comment: È isso mesmo notou a diferença? Espero que tenha ajudado.